# undefined reference to `cvFindHomography' ？

Tags: c++, opencv

When I want to build some OpenCV programme, it shows questions " undefined reference to `cvFindHomography' so I check that which header file contains this function, so I include` `...

But, it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to this site! To enable us to help you, we need detailled informationen about your problem and its environmental parameters. That is, _how_ do you build your application, and where were your OpenCV libraries installed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have included the appropriate header file, otherwise you would get a compiler error and not the linker error you reported. In C++ in most cases the header files only expose the declarations of functions you want to use. In your case the definition is found in the library file. You have to tell your linker to link your program against these lib files. See "4) Configure your own projects to use OpenCV" at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide on how to do this for OpenCV. In addition I recommend that you increase your knowledge about the c++ build system, i.e. what does your compiler, what does your linker etc.

Comment: It's OK,thanks very much !  I add lib in the .pro file like "LIBS += /usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so"  and it works. Thanks again.